# How to get the deep level node value easily when we don't have the object class with fastjson

Tags: c#, json, fastjson

I need to parse lots of long json strings. Newtonsoft.Json is slow and I try to use fastjson.

I don't have the object class so I use the following code to get values when using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
JObject jo = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(addressBook);
string floor = jo["Street"]["building"]["floor"].ToString();
```

When I turn to use fastjson and use the `JSON.Parse(string)`, I got an `Dictionary<string, object>`. And if I want to get the 'floor' value, I need to do the casting for each level like below:

```
var ob = (Dictionary<string, object>)JSON.Parse(addressBook);
var street = (Dictionary<string, object>)ob["Street"];
var building = (Dictionary<string, object>)street["building"];
var floor= (Dictionary<string, object>)building["floor"];
```

Does anyone know fastjson support it or not? And can it still be `fast`?

Comment: You can convert json to a class online http://csharp2json.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: @janfokketennapel the web site seems to be slow and can only convert c# class to json, not from json to class.

Comment: Since I have both the xml string and the json string of the `addressBook`, I tried to use xsd2code++ to generate the class and found that there are lots of modify to make. If there is a qualified tool to convert json to class, it will be good as well.